# Complex dynamically built query locks up when working on a low number of records, but is fine on a large set

Tags: query-performance, mariadb

We have a fairly complex query with multiple joins that is used to pull records from our CMS.

We have over two dozen sites running this multiple times daily with no issue. Some sites have thousands of records.

All of these sites have extremely similar schemas and all of the schemas are on the same MariaDB database.  Only those with around 10 or less records have an issue. Add records, and the issue goes away.

**UPDATED**

Someone asked more details on the failure state. When the query fails, the processer load goes to 100% memory utilization goes up by multiple gigabytes. If there is another load on the database, it will nearly hang the entire server until the mariaDB service gets restarted.

We are running an older version of Maria DB (5.5.68). Is this a possible factor?

What would cause a lock like this on a small data set, but not on a large one?

[image: Process list showing the query stuck multiple times]

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "locks up" - do these queries eventually complete? If so, how long does it take, approximately? Have you enabled the [slow query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-overview/) so you can capture the exact SQL queries being executed? Do the queries contain any instances of USE INDEX or [FORCE INDEX](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/force-index/)?

Comment: I have updated the question, essentially it ramps the CPU and nearly locks the server until an admin kills it. Sometimes the entire service has to be restarted as it's to slugish to even get in to kill the locked process. I will look into the slow query log (we have not). The query uses multiple joins, but no, it does not use FORCE INDEX.